# Is there a Ready function for ng-bind-html in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm using ng-bind-html of AngularJS. I have to initialize a plugin after my Binding function is over. So I would like to know if there is a method or a function to do that work ?

Thanks for you answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is initialise a `$watch` event over the variable you are using in your 'ng-bind'. Let m explain:

Suppose you have a span with an ng-bind like this:

```
<span ng-bind="val"></span>
```

Now, 'ng-bind' works in a way that whenever 'val' changes(within the digest cycle) it updates the value of the span, that is, it keeps a 'watch' on the 'val'. Similarly, we can use our own watch on the 'val' in the controller like this:

```
$scope.val; //your binded variable
$scope.$watch('val', function(newval, oldval) {
    //here you can initialise your plugin and also access the old and new values of 'val'
})
```